# Color management for EEVEE animation

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, color-management

I am rendering an animation in blender 3.1 using EEVEE. The colors of the rendered animation look totally different then the ones in the preview.

If I render a single frame then colors are right. How can I sort it out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Previews can vary from rendered animation mainly because of lighting differences.  So the first check is to make sure that the world lighting you're using is the same between the two and then see if there are any lights enabled in preview that aren't enabled in render.  EEVEE cuts corners with lighting so the next checks are to see if your material and lighting settings are different between preview and render where they can be.  Beyond that, maybe show us a screen grab of the viewport preview and one frame from the animation where it's different.